# How can you print multiple variables inside a string using printf?

Tags: c, printf, syntax-error

I want to find the maximum value of two numbers, and print it. I want to print all three numbers. I am using the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
     //clrscr();
     int a,b,c;
     printf("insert two numbers:");
     scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
     c = (a>b) ? a : b;
     printf("\nmaximum of %d",a," and %d",b,"  is = %d" c);
     getch();

}
```

However, I receive two syntax errors (Please find the attached figure). 
Could anybody help me out with it?

[image]

Comment: Put the `'\n'` at the end not the begining because it might not print anything unless another `'\n'` occurs or you explicitly call `fflush()`. Also, don't learn *conio.h* if you can and `main()` must return `int`.

Answer (score 36):

Change the line where you print the output to:

```
printf("\nmaximum of %d and %d is = %d",a,b,c);
```

See the docs [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 7):

```
printf("\nmaximum of %d and %d is = %d",a,b,c);
```